# config Jmeter Generating Report Dashboard Average response time millisecond to second

Tags: jmeter, report

in Jmeter http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html
we can see the response time is second not millisecond 
[transaction response time example from Jmeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyyIE.png)

but in my report it is millisecond not second, how can I config millisecond to second?
[My test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoQ3m.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The report is in Milliseconds not in seconds and it’s not configrable.

So check if you are not receiving error pages with a 200 response code and add assertions:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/best-practice-using-jmeter-assertions/

Also check your are following the prerequisites for the report:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#configuration_requirements